# Kubernetes: can ubuntu 18 containers run on slaves running on ubuntu 16?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, container

It seems to be possible for docker, is it the same case for kubernetes?

additional information on how this is implemented in technical terms would be useful as well. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real OS in a "Ubuntu 18 container". Docker images that bear the name of OSes are just telling you about:

- repos used when you install additional things
- software releases (and availability of some given packages in the repos)
- filesystem set up (there are differences in /etc)

Once the image is built the only important thing is the container process and its support libraries. These libs may depend on kernel features, but the typical K8S container will never use that. A K8S platform can run Docker containers built from Ubuntu, Debian, or CentOS images, not speaking of more "alien" things like Alpine.